# 404 Error On Custom Taxonomy Pages 2, 3, etc

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, 404-error, rewrite-rules

I've been reading a bunch of posts about this with no luck so far. I can't seem to figure out what is the problem.

I have the following:

Custom Post Type: Sermons

Custom Taxonomy: Series

My urls right now look like this mysite.com/Sermons/ParentTerm/ChildTerm/Post

When viewing the Parent Term of the series taxonomy the first page works fine. However when navigating to the next page using wordpress' pagination it throws a 404. So trying to view mysite.com/Sermons/ParentTerm/page/2/ does not work.

I'm guessing I need to do a URL rewrite? I tried the following with no luck:

```
function sermon_rewrite_rules() {
  add_rewrite_rule('sermons/%series%/([^/]+)/?$',
  'index.php?post_type=sermons&%series%=$matches[1]', 'top');
  add_rewrite_rule('sermons/%series%/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)?$',
  'index.php?post_type=players&type=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]','top');
}
add_filter('init', 'sermon_rewrite_rules');
```

I've tried reading up on everything I can about this and it's all starting to blur together, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT**

So after some tinkering around I have this working and allowing for paginaiton on taxonomy pages, but it's breaking my actual post now and displaying the terms there. I feel like I'm super close to the answer, any ideas?

```
function sermon_rewrite_rules() {
 add_rewrite_rule( 
    '^sermons/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(\d*)?',
    'index.php?series=$matches[1]&p=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]',
    'top' 
 );
}
add_filter('init', 'sermon_rewrite_rules');
```

Comment: Can you post how are you registering the custom post type and the custom taxonomy and how are you generating the custom permalink structure for the custom post and the custom taxonomy?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so after lots of reading, copying & pasting, and plugin installation I have finally gotten it to work.

This is using a custom post type: Sermons, a custom taxonomy: Series and allowing pagination on both pages.

First I downloaded this plugin here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/

Next I typed in the URL I wanted to change to get what I needed to rewrite, then ended up with the following working code:

```
function sermon_rewrite_rules() {
  add_rewrite_rule(
    'sermons/(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$', //THIS IS WHERE I PASTED INFO FROM PLUGIN
    'index.php?series=$matches[1]&p=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]',
    'top'
  );
}
add_filter('init', 'sermon_rewrite_rules');
```

Hope this can help someone else.

Comment: Your code may works for a while but I think it is not correct and you will end up with problems. See how you are using `$matches[1]`, `$matches[2]` and `$matches[3]` but the regex only catch two groups, so `$matches[3]` doesn't exist in any situation.